# How do I add one month to each date field in a column in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a column of date fields that contain different dates. I want to add 1 month to each of the dates.

So if my column/row is the following

```
A3: 1/2/2014
A4: 1/4/2014
A5: 1/10/2014
A6: 1/15/2014
```

Whatever formula or method I run will change everything to

```
A3: 2/2/2014
A4: 2/4/2014
A5: 2/10/2014
A6: 2/15/2014
```

Comment: If you want to do it programatically look into doing it with VBA, it's  pretty much VB tailored for Office applications which makes it nice and easy. To get you started you'll want to check out how to get a range of your cells into an object, how to iterate over it and how to use Application.WorksheetFunctions to overwrite the values of each cell with the updated date you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the EDATE function which adds a number of months to a give date.

```
EDATE(A1, 1)
```

will add one month to the date in cell A1.

Comment: The other answer got deleted but I tried this already. If you try to update the same field with the result excel warns you about a circular reference.

Comment: Why don't you just copy the cells that contain the dates to some other part of the worksheet and use my formula in their original place? So if your cells were A1 and A2, copy them say to Z1 and Z2 and turn A1=EDATE(Z1,1) and A2=EDATE(Z2,2). In general there are very few cases in Excel that you cannot handle with moving around some data and using formulas.

Answer (score 2):

> That won't do what I need it to do though. I want to update the existing cells to increase the date in each of them. I updated my question to (hopefully) make it clearer. – Scott 33 mins ago

From the comment under the deleted answer(Jerry) (*Since I can still see them :p*), I guess you want to use VBA. If that is the case then see this.You need to use the `DateAdd()`

If you check the Excel's help, `DateAdd` returns a Variant (Date) containing a date to which a specified time interval has been added.

**Syntax**

*DateAdd(interval, number, date)*

The interval argument has these settings:

```
Setting Description
yyyy    Year
q       Quarter
m       Month
y       Day of year
d       Day
w       Weekday
ww      Week
h       Hour
n       Minute
s       Second
```

Paste this in a module.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 3 To lRow
            .Range("A" & i).Value = DateAdd("m", 1, .Range("A" & i).Value)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with VBA so I guess i have to figure out how to implement this function. With this approach though how do you determine which fields it applies to? Do you select which cells you want to affect and then somehow apply the function to them?

Comment: You need to paste the code in a module. Also my code assumes that the dates are from Cell A3 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

Since in your example all your dates are in January, this should work: enter `31` in some cell and copy. Select your dates and Paste Special… Add. Simple, but big disadvantage is that this only works for 7 months of the year!